# Unable to parse server PHP on Swift app

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, parsing

I am trying to implement Signup/Login function on my iOS app.
For this, I have written a  simple server side php script, just to check that it return a value.
Here is my php code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["username"])){
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
if($username == "admin" && $password == "admin")
{
$details;
$details['success'] = $username;
echo json_encode($details);
}
else{
echo "invalid credential";
}
};
?>
```

And here is the code in Login screen:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/app/index.php")  
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST" 
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept") 
    //print("\(usernameField.text!), \(passwordField.text!), \(emailField.text!)")  
    //let params = ["user":"\(usernameField.text!)","pass":"\(passwordField.text!)"] as NSDictionary  
    let bodyData = "username=\(usernameField.text)&password=\(passwordField.text)"  
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in
            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
                print("json is : \(json!)")
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    let firstNameValue = parseJSON["success"] as? String
                    print("Username: \(firstNameValue!)")
                }
            } catch {
                print("errorrrrr: \(error)")
            }  
            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error!)")
                return
            }        
            // You can print out response object
            print("Response = \(response!)")
            // Print out reponse body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("response Data = \(responseString!)")


        })
        task.resume()

}
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

And my Response Data is **"Invalid Credentials"**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your php script is not complete for a webservice. It is not returning a json. You will have to complete your webservice first. I am not a php guy. But still I tried to improve the script :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"])){
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
if($username == "admin" && $password == "admin")
{
    $details;
    $details['success'] = $username;
    return json_encode($details);
}
else{
    return json_encode( array("response" => "invalid credential") );
}
};
?>
```

Update : Use the below code for hitting the webservice after itegrating the alamofire library:

```
let parameters = ["username": usernameField.text! ,"password" : passwordField.text! ]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost/app/index.php", parameters: parameters)
     .responseString { response in
         print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
     }
     .responseJSON { response in
         print("Response JSON: \(response.result.value)")
       //Handle the json response here
      if let parseJSON = response.result.value {
                let firstNameValue = parseJSON["success"] as? String
                print("Username: \(firstNameValue!)")
            }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow & let you know.

Comment: Yes and I am sure the error is in swift code. Can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Why don't you use Alamofire. It handles the jSon by default. We need not care about it. Just integrate the library to your project. Heres the instructions to do so: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: We, I changed the php file to the required file that I need for my project and it is working. Thanks, anyways

Comment: No idea, considering php script itself is not wrong. It must be that the request that is sent from app must behave in a different way. The new php code involves a lot of database connections and other stuff. My friend gave me that file. However, in Swift code, I did make 1 change. I put the json parsing code inside "response block".